# Integration OpenAM - OAuth2 with iOS

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0, keychain, openam

I am developing an application for iOS and need to integrate with OAuth 2.0 and OpenAM. I'm in doubt how to delegate the refresh token for KeyChain.